Entropy production and anisotropies in compact Bianchi type VIIh "universes"...?
I had a couple of questions concerning this interesting paper where the authors hypothesize how could anisotropic "stresses" be exploited to produce entropy (they indicate that an example of that would be Lukash planewaves). Of course the paper proposes only a hypothetical scenario (they assume an open universe with negative curvature), but I'm interested in whether their conclusions could be applied to other models of the universe with other conditions as well (at least theoretically):
At the end of it, the authors say that their conclusions do not apply for Bianchi type VIIh compact universes since Lukash plane waves (which are explained in the paper) are not solutions of Einstein's equations unless the shear (sigma) is 0. However, I tried to ask this question to one of the authors and he replied:

In the case where the shear approaches zero, a compact space can still sustain indefinite information processing. If shear is exactly zero, then no. A compact space with shear > 0 can evolve towards a shear = 0 but never reach mathematically exact shear = 0.

So a compact Bianchi type VIIh universe could sustain information processing in the way that is described in the paper in some cases after all?

" the authors hypothesize how could anisotropic "stresses" be exploited to produce entropy" Can you explain why that might be desirable?
